# Why different size when converting PIL Image to Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I've found it bizarre that numpy arrays and PIL images have different shape, in this case, `(H,W)` in numpy and `(W,H)` in PIL. My versions are,

> Name: numpy Version: 1.13.3
>
> Name: Pillow Version: 4.1.1

```
IMG = '/path/to/test-image.jpg'

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

with Image.open(IMG) as img:
    print img.size
    img_np_f = np.asarray(img, order='F')
    print img_np_f.shape
    img_np_c = np.asarray(img, order='C')
    print img_np_c.shape

    plt.subplot(131)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.subplot(132)
    plt.imshow(img_np_f)
    plt.subplot(133)
    plt.imshow(img_np_c)
    plt.show()
```

The output goes,

```
(320, 240)
(240, 320)
(240, 320)
```

However, it seems matplotlib handles it correctly anyway.

[image]

Comment: Interesting observation, but what is your question?

Comment: @KenS. I am asking why is so, making it incoherent?

Answer (score 1):

Because `Numpy` is not an imaging library.

`numpy.ndarray.shape` gives the shape in this order `(H, W, D)` to stay coherent with the terminology used in `ndarray`'s axis `(axis=0, axis=1, axis=2)`

Comment: so the height dimension in PIL is considered as the first axis by numpy?